# WP8 Development on Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio Express 2013, fully updates to R2 and all. I've got all the WP8 emulators and such. Basically, I have everything needed for WP development. Problem is, there is nothing on developing WP8 apps in VSE 2013. I can't get the templates.
Anyway, I'm running Windows 8.1, I've unlocked my phone (Lumia 925) and I'm all ready for Windows Phone development. I'm wondering if there is any way I can develop WP8 apps with VSE 2013. I'm willing to downgrade to 2012 if needed. But, I don't have the money for Visual Studio Ultimate or any premium version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have VS2013 for WP development. You need VS2012 Express for WP and you have tools/SDK for VS2013 Express

Check these
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx
http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-phone
http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk