# No template for Windows Phone 8.1 in Visual Studio Express 2013 with Update 2 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express, windows-phone-8.1

I have been developing WP (Windows Phone) 8.0 apps using Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone. To start developing for WP 8.1, I downloaded VS 2013 including update 2 RC from [Windows Phone Developer site](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) which is supposed to use to develop WP 8.1 apps.

I've tried twice, but there is no option to create WP 8.1 app even after a successful installation. What I get is only this:

[image: image link]

i.e. no option to create Windows Phone 8.1 apps. If it matters, I'm interested in WP 8.1 Visual C# template specifically.

As I've mentioned, since I develop Windows Phone 8.0 apps, therefore Visual Studio Express (2012) for Windows Phone is already installed.

I've already gone through:

[WP8 Development on Visual Studio Express 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156122/wp8-development-on-visual-studio-express-2013)
[Why is there no Windows Phone version of Visual Studio Express 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230702/cannot-create-a-windows-phone-app-in-javascript-in-ms-visual-studio-2013)
[Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177560/visual-studio-2013-and-windows-phone)
[How to get started with windows phone SDK 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125570/how-to-get-started-with-windows-phone-sdk-8-1)
[WP8 Development on Visual Studio Express 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156122/wp8-development-on-visual-studio-express-2013)

but none address the solution.

Comment: So you are running VS 2013 Update 2 RC on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Quick question, is WP8.1 development supported on Win7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the solution.

I downloaded both Visual Studio 2013, and update 2 RC using the /layout switch at command prompt. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx):

> After you download the update executable from the MSDN website to a
>   location on your file system, run the following command at a command
>   prompt:  /layout.
>
> This command downloads all the
>   packages for the installation. By using the /layout switch, you can
>   download all the installation packages, not just the ones that apply
>   to the download machine. This approach gives you all the files that
>   you need to run this update anywhere and may be useful if you want to
>   install components that weren't installed originally.

To do this, download the Visual Studio 2013, and Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC files (about 2-3 MBs each). Then, create a shortcut of these files on desktop, and then open properties of shortcut. In target field after ", add a space followed with /layout as shown below:

[image: how to enter /layout switch]

This will download all installation files to your disk and when you install the VS (the exe at specified download folder), it won't ask it to fetch from internet, rather will do it from offline files and phone SDK 8.1 will be installed too.

Please be warned that, this will take a lot of time. To save time, I suggest following what is in Update section.

### Update

While searching on internet, I found these two links on Microsoft website:

> [Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows
>   Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40787)
>
> [Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update
>   2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42670)

In download section, these two sites show that, the offline download option is now available (as evident from the ISOs shown). Though, I don't know if that would help as I haven't tested this option. Just that this option will be much more quicker than using /layout switch.

Answer (score 8):

[image: The Location on my Visual studio]

Being a windows app developer even I was baffled with the shift in Windows Phone location. You can find it in

> Visual C# --> Store Apps --> Windows Phone apps.

Do sign in, in Visual Studio through Microsoft Account then go to ur notification and update ur VS and you will get this screen. Its usually caused due to some updates working only when VS can access developer's account and also I am using VS 2013 pro.

Have you installed Windows phone emulator SDK with the updated emulators?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if you closely see the picture attached, you'll see there are no sub options in 'store apps'

Comment: Yes I saw that thats why I asked you to download the latest SDK and emulator updates and also try to Login in Visual studio and then check the notification area since some update works only after u login.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't find it at all until I read your post. I knew I installed the SDK, but was shocked that I couldn't find it. I almost had to resort to reinstalling the entire app. Why did they move it? I guess to follow the "code-once" philosophy they're moving towards?

Comment: Glad I was able to help you. Yes you are right- Universal Apps and combining Windows Stores are some steps followed in pursuit of this philosophy. Happy Coding