# VS 2012 Express does not have windows phone template project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm new to Windows Phone 8 development and hence on my windows surface pro I have installed VS 2012 Express along with Windows Phone 8.1 sdk.
But when I open new project in VS 2012 Express version it does not have Windows Phone template project for C#. How do I proceed.
Do i need to install VS 2012 Professional edition or Express will do?

Thanks.

Comment: You ma wanna take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319443/no-template-for-windows-phone-8-1-in-visual-studio-express-2013-with-update-2-rc)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx). It is freeware and has more features than Express.